# Google Drive Update keeps throwing an error when I try to save a thumbnail

Tags: google-drive-api

The Base64 string checks out fine. I was able to export it to another website and download it again as my image. When I try to do an update using the Drive Javascript api, it just keeps returning this error:

```
Invalidvaluefor:Notavalidbase64bytestring
```

I also true making the string URL safe. Per this page
https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/drive/v2/python/latest/drive_v2.files.html

Am I doing something wrong here, the documentation says send Base64, the string is valid and, the string is intact throughout the process, but Google will not accept it?

I am using the javascript api, I think there is maybe a bug sending the thumbnail using the javascript api.

This is the request

```
Request URL:https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/?uploadType=multipart
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Bad Request

**Request Headers**
:host:www.googleapis.com
:method:POST
:path:/upload/drive/v2/files/?uploadType=multipart
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
authorization:Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQr...YXDacdY4
content-length:14313
content-type:multipart/mixed; boundary="--mpart_delim"
origin:https://www.googleapis.com
x-javascript-user-agent:google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0-beta
x-origin:https://app.pinteract.com
x-referer:https://app.pinteract.com

**Query String Parameters**
uploadType:multipart

**Request Payload**
----mpart_delim
Content-Type: application/json

{"id":null,"title":"Test Pinup.pint","mimeType":"application/vnd.pinteract.pint","thumbnail":{"mimeType":"image/png","image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...UVORK5CYII%3D"}}
----mpart_delim
Content-Type: application/vnd.pinteract.pint
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

{
"header" :
{"id":"215A660A"}
"members" :
[
{"id":"100523752012631912873"}
],
"manifest" :
[
{"id":"0000","ele":[],"own":"100523752012631912873","dtc":1371679680000,"txt":"&Delta; Created","typ":0}
],
"elements" :
[
{"id":"0F54","x":560,"y":264,"bak":"#44ff44","own":"100523752012631912873","srt":"544","sta":0,"wid":120,"hgt":120,"dtc":0,"rec":"","txt":"This is Note"}
]
}
----mpart_delim--

**Response Headers**
content-length:10848
content-type:application/json
date:Mon, 01 Jul 2013 14:41:33 GMT
server:HTTP Upload Server Built on Jun 25 2013 11:32:14 (1372185134)
status:400 Bad Request
version:HTTP/1.1
```

This is the Response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid value for: Not a valid base64 byte string: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...AASUVORK5CYII%3D"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value for: Not a valid base64 byte string: iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU...lRtkAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D"
 }
}
```

Raw Base64 String

```
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
```

Url Encoded Base64 String

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAYAAADimHc4AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAADjVJREFUeNrsXX2MHVUVP3fevH27SxfKhyBCsIqoKOhCBBISY5Hyj2JSGuXLP6SJwYAYICgxsUBr1AhqbE2I8Q9jjYE%2FCLFbP4IxVbaIYjAmS0wUC6ELRGy7tPt2t9vd997MPd6Z%2B3Xunfsq1r7tvNe56TAfO2%2FezO93zu%2Fce%2B6ZB0DVqla1qlWtalWrWtWqVrWqVa1qJ1Nj%2FXCTm5%2BbHeUcz9%2B3f25tmvLVSYePIyLIBRhX24yxKXH63Kljw5Ni97UfbVhzpCLgGNs3%2Fjp%2F%2Fr9en72l3UnWCsCvSjrpmQA54Nkq28q3FQn5mucL5OuIsUPi6f5Si6KJVasaT26%2F%2BT1vVgS8hfbl3%2B27br65dE%2Br1VknrH6IIfkjolmh%2FA8hwYJv1lySInYXhXc8W49r235%2B%2ByVPVQQE2lee3n%2Fd3OzS5tZS%2B2oWurlMYgj4qI45HsApCZYAzgFSsU7FfhSx5%2BtxtHnnHR9%2BqiJAtPsnD1y4MLf09aXF9q3ZzTAmb8ohQaKtHEDLkGv9qIBHBbgmICXrlKyjKHoirkWbfn3X%2BEsnLQH37dr3mebs4o8x4WMSfGbAtyQoDSLga8BBeQJqqXE8QQIt12D2syVR2%2BLcxVpcu%2F23d1%2F%2B%2BElFwPdeXB555eWZ7x453LozEvuRtvqMgCyAhm7QyI7Sf7BEcI4mCNP9lBKhrD9R2zkJqVwLWfpOYyje8tSXLlsceAIy8Pf8Y98vOq1kXQZ8JG5By06kLZ%2F5%2Bm8DcEiCMt3XXpCTwN0YkKrYkFu%2F0CfpCSC3M1IEEeILJ0ca9et%2Fc%2FfliwNLQAb%2BSxR8JTkRJUAdy4DOtxCdQGyDb6ALyq0HuEHYyo%2BOAYlaUkVI7hkAk8ON%2BPpd935kceAIMOC3BfjiayUB1gO0FAG4QTjfN9pTjAO0%2F0%2B9ICeDBmGyJDQoEzIyjxCr3YKET%2F7%2BvitWhIRopQh4%2BZ%2F7fyAtX4PPQG%2FX1JLt19Rit8XfIjDb7uftdWqa0Ox8sNfIF%2FCvK4mPFAB6yf4uaPzYYit5dKVwWREC7vrV619sLXU%2BL8Gg4AEBlXgFBdN8JgQ6M%2BfUHJDJNWiQD1yHkXOlDLLMcz53xTf%2FdNtASNBXn5l598y%2B%2Bb%2BL3k2j5gFdU1KkA2%2FkdEOR9IDsOpSCQBN4M%2F3nJuCaOEC03pEhJTuJJ0XtbEHsxBG75PmvXb2nrz3gzZnD2wVCjQgYsUAgVm2lRwdiR6LA9w4lS2YNnlcRq%2FavB653MfrdnueJf%2FXllP%2BkryXozl%2B%2BtoF30o9GnoVrvZU9HtINNaD44BFgHSmx4DP%2FswRkKz9F3WcGCOt9NQ0MwtWXbnn2xr4loL2cbNYDLAdcQgTz9FpbtAaUERANsJEFklHvIOMISiBzrqlJD4w%2FyKJJEL2lh%2FqSgDt2vrohTdJL%2FQdzBlvMtUQ6Io6cXgwBngZWD%2FxIeZVeM49o5g30KEGh%2B1Td4g%2B8f%2FMfbuw7Atotbf0EVOchmQuGts5APsh4UNCbSBoDPE%2FoYt3B48zekzEIVF7Ae%2BcFPSHgCxOvXpwm%2FFLHslQ6GZgLfNfFk54iuMwhyAf2aJLTfcHg8cwLLnzwmQ%2F2DQFCem4pgOR4gzviLQDD3gIRzE1h%2BPshyaEB3wPYORccImVyUHR1P9s3BCSd9CZ%2FsOFPsjCV4ymkHViYCJOmYEV5co8xF1DnHrDwfe6cg1wzdZCRE8WY4tN9QYAY9Z4rBj7vzZNpiMWRHqJ5yKMCQcBg3cgJkpFPzjtkRw7x%2BruwqxQBkUxNnGgXXbBp8rzSE3BksT3uZDDJUJahD7hKsGFACug%2BCx8vegQWRtEsOOzHwO1h8WEQncOiSzpeegLaneQqB2wMEKHWGHhgigUzs2FYsHyAcNzonmfBgneZBfDoORk03nlF6QkQffCL3WdFM4uFSLUWHcuzTqPrTtCdkvSMlwb5ozZVPQHo3g8L%2BqgjOZ7t5HvHvScUH%2FceUMrPrmkTzW%2BagbRrZswIkXmGKHUbPWCQWDH6shUK8n4g9aVQGQFT3%2BkYguGdGAoWHOas0nsAqowlnbUyD%2BBPpoNX56M%2FR7wAzHkItjLCDaQO1gZXBOcQ3Tego4dzYAsBMBw5yukB8o6ZARiVZSs7l8e8NSOKr60euwRM39J1bZBZG%2FKsRTuxhRoE%2BQ6T3gZqNPk0pWUXsfwEaA%2FIHyQHX1sZM%2FCiY9OWLH0GJ66ZSwYJuoYgDxMj9QiFeiFbzIWGA3oOBKrvdIWF9j9Z8NUPHoBoQUVq7RJsbnpCTIFNgEeZUANFghmZogWeYVG6bAmirYqgJSwFItC3eNdwqIdwpN7SBx7A0YZdRCo1ECQiMlYvk3WcDJAi7QGBYAzepDyqSXlTpKXWEPAI7sQk7RmWJFPeqGXInNcHHtBKUhiJa%2FKBsoq0CBSwQJIENg2RP7AqyNIdpYhYnfYI9KYo%2FSlJWxdKSSHgBTyAQzfZcqc9OfGG0veC4ijaTcsEgdZskqo1W7%2FjVrbpEhL6N7kPzpwu99dqHljPDaNXqGuvby0cQyQpY%2BEK8BSsV4i2u%2FQecLjdmR4biq2Gc5WCZmgSXJwzKeYkqqKyfDqyjZT12VEtFrqZ6FTC0bJ0S7AGMD8PSB2R8RjrOUhK3FPQniIlSpAxXXoCFlrJ1Kp6rLScmVElU2gzf5TFbJIMzawYM8GWBXI4tEoaObrvB5A6UBMLPI8qWj6aLmdeyqjApx6QSqKmjjdePSlL%2BdQPX5gdjqPVea2OKqqyBVFuXZCukgOg9TvZMVuamGc3%2FRJFJAMsXqyOowW53CtF0UW6VtK4qpgGaIvtlrhOS6yz8hS5na2xefDha0%2Fvg4FYrsUT4v5vy1PD3JUfSjnKMZvt66PNxWA%2Bk8VtahjdHhCQFzVoebpTC0S2uV%2B2SOOCkSFl%2FWitPy9hlN4x0TcTMjOLrZ1GRwMFsno77yVxWjzlWqUTfNH%2Fu1to637GBT8%2Fjxbr6uCOhBR1TqplCKTscNDygzt7gVXPKuM%2B8ejUbKOWyRCt61TlHqYQihVKSY7%2Bloy0eqZAgkCRrl8d7b8Zk5rXlVSlnC5bF8dasiJOV8Zp6RHb0DzUA%2FnpmQfkwXi5s80CwF2rRbdc0PEQ9eJEwdqJ9yQFj%2BHBc5MA%2BNx5m9LuJ0R%2B8hhhJCgnd1uvcOoZAS%2Fsn9sqBmVNCnoIzAJwafdj%2BuUKnvKuwCeBgCutHozM%2BDEhUYDbNSgScu1vit2tfUfA%2FCPrmgvtRHqBM4gCByBOQKTAUPAl8FwAb4tpE97dS5JuZFNZUtadKsATQ4RYAIhHwLameJa%2BIyBrfzswv3WxI7yASIEPjvumilpS1xMK3UjHe3xC1DXQexmDyhEJwh2OLviuJwjgcWsvMep5efr4t55b%2F%2FZThnbk4wBw%2B%2F6F2n3wS0v8EnUyIYM0tex1Q8l26qUkUjViThT4HZSLDLyQB9%2BODLzZuTcI65%2FoawKyduW3%2F7zj9OH6%2BihEgDcA82t3GEBxMkQBqntFvPC%2BMDjdS5qm0IGWgt%2FRwKveT7Yvjk8I8G%2FoNTbxShDw4qHDGz901tia0bg2jirvo9fcIQC7lJ%2Bgk6RHPdEPUMhcOj9ZAMW353O5kgAroNU2pxKUpxw2rgQ2K%2FaS3jsf3D1%2B%2Fqrhp0fE2MCkIzwJ6lYy6Fu%2FJcCf8QqMB8Baf6JAT8i2lp9EyY441hSfuWbukXVTA0VATsIDu8fPO6Xx9HBGAi1NJ2XkAMUKtcKcJ523JeBz5ycLbMo5VUDbtZYgua%2FBF72fpvjMNc0VAn%2FFCcjaBQ9Mjr9jtJF7An1zhQZiO0VvM6VQSEdbDwCPACpDKenVpMbybW9Hb2ejXfHpFQX%2FhBCQk7Bpcvzs4aEdo3G0hr4fHEGoiNdNRdOUhEuElSOdTEvABt2EkNFx%2Bv3CCwCmUfZ4plYaixP2Yx2n3r9r9QWnNHasrsdrQ68KwX8hAOiEjJ421H18oGkFRQSXg6%2BO7gUZr4BJcYUbejnYKiUBuq3ZNHnPGY36Q42IrWYBL2B%2B4Szt%2F2vZAfJDTd6kigZeSw7J82R6v2X2kXVbT%2BTzl%2BIHm4Q3rDlnuP6Q6KbeVjfxAPWbis7NojcdqSfWubJ8riUIrAfo1ENiPAS2i2NbRE9n%2BkQ%2Fe6l%2Bsuw0QcSZwhtEL8kQQUvbTb0aLec0lk9Gv2AHYwkhQvzbLpYthx6%2Bdrosz1zKH%2B3LPGIsrq2PDu79%2FvA5F8p3igMEAFjZQV%2BCrCxNicM%2FFdY%2FUQaL7wsCdBsZGcH6GefB2EVXwsi574Pa294FSeM0aNVPpeMyFYQRhtrzEC0dgnTmFWi9sQcW9k5NLr2x5%2BPQm7ra%2FklF%2FF8WcngG4r1%2FhLG5F%2BHsQ%2BfA6OgoDDUaEMdx9rtv0vLTFNqdDrSWl2FhYQEOHNgPyeysCLOzzAsfpWsRDH5jZfb2gSQA3fQFKzMJJ4sHlJaEeFA9QHlB6G1YLFNMGGAPQPqMrKyeEMNgN5pg5V08AU6kNwwsASQQUy%2FnXdzkhElSPODgs4DMhkioPKA3RJgfvwoFCN6FkIqA4xwDQgTo90eSKgj3oHGe0q5oHBgVZwR0ql5Qz2MAhjwg%2B2O7Goj1VvtpD6jugb8AJUrMDagEcToSjgn48yCrzkvTBjYZx7khoK6e82AZgu5JQ4Bqi%2BoZ%2F10m3e8bAgSQE8dOQE7CJMh3e5fL%2BoylJiCKom3HSoBYDqdp%2BpjYLfX%2FTa%2FUBBw5cmSSMbb1WAhgLNqYJMnLZZfL0seAZrN5rwDzfyGhWa%2FXNx48%2BOaT%2FRCv%2BiIIT0%2FvvbfRaFwjvOFoMSErLdxeq9Uu27v3le390mFg0IftpptvXetURXDefPyxn01B1apWtapVrWpVq1rVqla1t9L%2BI8AAvydNUrElRtkAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D
```

Comment: Could you provide more information such as full error code and your source code?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this exact problem and struggled with it for a while.  It seems the drive API doesn't like the standard base64 format as it is not url-safe (contains '+', '/', and '=').

It also doesn't seem to like the base64 string when it is url-encoded with encodeURIComponent().

What it *will* accept, however, is the [base64url format of Base64](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5).  The only difference between the two is that the '+' character is replaced with '-', and the '/' character is replaced with '_'.

I was able to successfully upload a thumbnail when I converted the string like so:

```
var rawBase64 = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...UVORK5CYII="; // your raw base64
var data = rawBase64.replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
```

Hope this helps somebody else.  The drive docs weren't very clear on how the string should be formatted.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will try it in the next iteration. I will not forget to check this answer if it works. It sounds very promising.

Comment: Note that there may well be further changes necessary. See https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_photo and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 (search for base64url).